# Make image data from REST API viewable

Tags: php, image, api, rest

I am making a GET request to a REST API using PHP to call an image.  In the response body, I get something like this:

> ÿØÿàJFIF`` `ÿÛC     $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC
>
>   2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ0$"ÿÄ
>
>   ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚
>
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ
>
>   ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ
>   $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?óä·ï7ç]W„üÚè{«©äŽÁ ``òÛæ•‡P`:ëÇjË–ÖO$¬#39    ûÌp¿©ìö61iö6öP(X
>   cP=†3ýhŸºð…ql"Ž   ­œ–X§bÃë¸^g«h·Z>§-Ë’ê7#®@‘FÈŽÄWºm®KÇÖmÕ_žÒeŽJ9GæTþäæÙó÷›ó¢¶Í¯=(
>   û+d]FÄÈ>QwþŒ\W¦¨® æÊG¶o#eÃÄOMêw/êw·)umÄrT¿B3@¬_ “Ã—Ê{

What should I do with this to make it a viewable image?

Comment: can you please show how you embed the image once you fetched it? Is this in an `<img>` tag or do you fetch it via an HTTP client?

Comment: Did you try using fiddler, because that would show the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the appropriate image [`header`](http://php.net/header). Check the [Content-Type heade](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)r to see what format it is. In case this is not the image binary but compressed content, run it through [`gzuncompress`](http://php.net/gzuncompress) first.

Comment: I am sending in content-type: image/jpg but it is still coming back like this?

Comment: @motboys The webserver does not have to adhere to what you request. But try with gzuncompress or gzdeflate first. You can look at the headers to see whether its compressed.

Comment: thank you.  I wasn't sure what this response was but now I realize it's a binary stream.  Once I sent header("Content-type: image/jpg") and echoed out the variable holding the binary data, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do with this to make it a viewable image?

Assuming the context is an HTML document, use an `<img />` tag to display the response in your document.  Set its `src` attribute to the URI of the script that requests the image:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.php?id=..." />
```

In your PHP script, you will simply want to `echo` the binary image data after setting the appropriate headers (covered in Gordon's answer).